# Output of semaphore values

Tags: c, semaphore

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t s1, s2;
pthread_t foo_tid, bar_tid;

void *foo(void*) {
  while(1) {
    sem_wait(&s1);
    printf("HI ");
    sem_post(&s2);
  }
}

void *bar(void*) {
  while(1) {
    sem_wait(&s2);
    printf("HO ");
    sem_post(&s1);
  }
}

int main() {
  sem_init(&s1, 0, 0);
  sem_getvalue(&s1, &foo_tid);
  sem_init(&s2, 0, 0);
  sem_getvalue(&s2, &bar_tid);
  pthread_create(&foo_tid, NULL, foo, NULL);
  pthread_create(&bar_tid, NULL, bar, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get the output of the semaphores `s1` and `s2`. But I keep getting these errors:

```
sema.c: In function 'main':
sema.c:29:3: warning: passing argument 2 of 'sem_getvalue' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from sema.c:6:0:
/usr/include/semaphore.h:72:12: note: expected 'int * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'pthread_t *'
sema.c:31:3: warning: passing argument 2 of 'sem_getvalue' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from sema.c:6:0:
/usr/include/semaphore.h:72:12: note: expected 'int * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'pthread_t *'`
```

I just haven not been able to get rid of this error. If anyone could help me out with this, that'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you read the [`sem_getvalue` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_getvalue.3.html)? What does it tell you its parameter types need to be and what did you give it? Also, what does reading the warning message tell you very directly "expected..but argument is.."?

Comment: You got a clear, (or as clear as can be expected:), compiler error message, complaining of a type mismatch on the second parameter of 'sem_getvalue'.  That happened because you have a  type mismatch on the second parameter of 'sem_getvalue'.

Comment: Remove the `sem_getvalue` calls. They have no purpose as used. When `pthread_create` is called, it does _not_ dereference the value for _reading_. It only uses the pointer to _set_ a tid value on return (i.e.) the value set before the call is ignored [and replaced]. Further, because a `sem_init` is done before the `sem_getvalue`, the value will always be zero.

Answer (score 0):

From [sem_getvalue](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_getvalue), values should be int :

Declare `int s1_val, s2_val;`

```
  sem_init(&s1, 0, 0);
  sem_getvalue(&s1, &s1_val);
  sem_init(&s2, 0, 0);
  sem_getvalue(&s2, &s2_val);
```

Comment: Changing it to int gets another error though, for pthread_create

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is expected to be a pointer to `int`, where as you are passing in the address of a `pthread_t`. A `pthread_t` is not an `int` on your system.